# Where and how do I properly make an event listener?

Tags: java, architecture

I want to recreate an event architecture similar to the [JDA](https://github.com/discord-jda/JDA) architecture, but in the process of creation I encountered problem listener implementation. I have no idea how to do it at all for such an architecture, and I could not find a listener in JDA. If you know how to implement a listener, or at least know where it is located in JDA, please let me know.

https://github.com/AdaMorgan/event-arch <- my repository

Comment: Is this the method you need from JDA? https://github.com/discord-jda/JDA/blob/master/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDABuilder.java#L1780

Comment: @Jhilton, you can notice that from build() it passes the listened classes further, and after that I get lost, and I can’t find where and how it listens to methods from the ListenerAdapter

Comment: For conceptual background you may look for the Observer Pattern. For JDA specific implementation, I think the classes of interest for listening to events are these: 
https://github.com/discord-jda/JDA/blob/master/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/internal/JDAImpl.java

https://github.com/discord-jda/JDA/blob/e5136944e83947eb8a5381a37de4788f1bb196bf/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/internal/hooks/EventManagerProxy.java#L29

https://github.com/discord-jda/JDA/blob/e5136944e83947eb8a5381a37de4788f1bb196bf/src/main/java/net/dv8tion/jda/api/hooks/InterfacedEventManager.java#L42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you create your own `EventObject`. Here’s an example from one of my projects.

```
import bean.InmateDataBean;
import java.util.EventObject;

public class PhotoEventObject extends EventObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected InmateDataBean inmate;

    public PhotoEventObject(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }

    public InmateDataBean getInmate() {
        return inmate;
    }

    public void setInmate(InmateDataBean inmate) {
        this.inmate = inmate;
    }

}
```

There’s nothing special about this class, other than it extends `EventObject`. Your constructor is defined by `EventObject`, but you can create any getter and setter methods you want.

Second, you define an `EventListener` interface.

```
public interface EventListener {
    public void handleEvent(PhotoEventObject eo);
}
```

You would use the `EventObject` you created. You can use any method name that you want. This is the interface for the code that will be written as a response to the listener.

Third, you write a `ListenerHandler`. Here’s mine from the same project.

```
import bean.InmateDataBean;
import main.EventListener;
import main.PhotoEventListener;
import main.PhotoEventObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PhotoListenerHandler {

    protected List<EventListener> listeners;

    public PhotoListenerHandler() {
        listeners = new ArrayList<EventListener>();
    }

    public void addListener(EventListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(EventListener listener) {
        for (int i = listeners.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            EventListener instance = listeners.get(i);
            if (instance.equals(listener)) {
                listeners.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void fireEvent(final PhotoEventObject eo,
            final InmateDataBean inmate) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listeners.size(); i++) {
            final EventListener instance = listeners.get(i);
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    eo.setInmate(inmate);
                    instance.handleEvent(eo);
                }

            };
            new Thread(runnable).start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("This line goes in your DataHandlerMain class "
                + "constructor.");
        PhotoListenerHandler handler = new PhotoListenerHandler();
        System.out.println("I need you to put the commented method in "
                + "DataHandlerMain so I can use the handler instance.");

        // public PhotoListenerHandler getPhotoListenerHandler() {
        //      return handler;
        // }

        System.out.println("This line goes in the GUI code.");
        handler.addListener(new PhotoEventListener());

        System.out.println("Later, when you've received the response from "
                + "the web service...");
        InmateDataBean inmate = new InmateDataBean();
        inmate.setIntKey(23);
        handler.fireEvent(new PhotoEventObject(handler), inmate);
    }
}
```

The main method in this class shows you how you use a `ListenerHandler`. The rest of the methods in the class are standard. You would use your own `EventObject` and `EventListener`.